# common values of 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a file with 3 columns. the 1st column is `ID`, 2nd and 3rd are values for 2 conditions. in condition columns I have both `-` and `+` values. I would like to make 2 separate files. the 1st one would be for the negative values and the 2nd one would be for the positive values. do you know how to that in R?

Comment: Add [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected output. 2 columns with 2 different values, would give you 4 outputs: `"--", "-+", "+-", "++"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:5,cond1 = sample(-100:100,5), cond2 = sample(-100:100,5))
df_neg <- df_pos <- df1
df_pos[,2:3][df1[,2:3]<0] <- NA # or 0, or NULL
df_neg[,2:3][df1[,2:3]>0] <- NA # or 0, or NULL

# > df1
# id cond1 cond2
# 1  1   -47    80
# 2  2   -26    88
# 3  3    13    31
# 4  4    79    24
# 5  5   -61   -88
# > df_pos
# id cond1 cond2
# 1  1    NA    80
# 2  2    NA    88
# 3  3    13    31
# 4  4    79    24
# 5  5    NA    NA
# > df_neg
# id cond1 cond2
# 1  1   -47    NA
# 2  2   -26    NA
# 3  3    NA    NA
# 4  4    NA    NA
# 5  5   -61   -88
```